# meaning and output of date command in Unix

Tags: unix

I am facing difficulty in understanding  the below date command and its output in Unix if pass the value of 'end' as 130?
Thanks in advance.

**date --date='{{ end }} day' +%s**

Answer (score 2):

The `date` will give the current date time.
With `--date='{{ end }} day'` you are adding **end** number of days to current date time.

The `+%s` outputs the overall **Unix timestamp** after adding end number of days.

Refer [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

You specify intended date format with -**-date** option:

Which accepts rich set of format options : Please go through [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/date-command-linux-examples/)

If you put 130 as value of **end** unix variable then you will get Date and time after 130 days followed by seconds as well because **+%s** prints seconds.

Comment: I am getting value as 1583059907 after I put end value as 130.but my question is what does that value mean?